# Is there a TQDM like module for creating progress bars for recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, progress-bar, tqdm

I am writing a branch and bound algorithm in python and I am trying to efficiently display the progress.  The algorithm uses recursion and I couldn't figure out any way to make it iterative.  I am wondering if there is a tqdm like module for recursive functions or at least a way to implement a progress bar with recursive functions?  For example, if I was writing an iterative factorial function in python with the tqdm module I would do this:

```py
import tqdm

def factorial(n):
    end_product = 1
    for i in tqdm(range(1, n)):
        end_product *= i
    return end_product
```

How would I implement a progress bar on a recursive function like this:

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

progress_bar(factorial(1000))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One solution is initialize progress bar with `total=` parameter and then call `.update()` method in each call of recursion.

Something along the lines of this:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm

def factorial(n, bar):
    bar.update(1)
    sleep(0.01)  # slow-down things a little bit
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1, bar)

n = 500
bar = tqdm(total=n)
factorial(n, bar=bar)
```